# HttpSecurity.authorizeRequests deprecado en SpringBoot 3.1.1

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

se que este tema ha salido antes, pero al parecer la solucion la volvieron a deprecar en la version 3.0.0 y no se como deberia sustituir la configuracion de seguridad web de mi proyecto.
Estimados, por favor su ayuda!!... lo que necesito saber es los respectivos cambios que debo aplicar para la **version 3.1.0** de SpringBoot que estoy usando, porque ya probe con los cambios de la 3.0.0 y tampoco resulto.

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService serviceUsuario;
    
    String[] resources = new String[] { "/include/**", "/js/**", "/css/**"}; 
    
    @Bean
    BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
    
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(serviceUsuario).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder()) ;
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(resources).permitAll() 
                .and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/console/**").permitAll() 
                .and().authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated() 
                .and().httpBasic()
                .and().formLogin()               
                .failureUrl("/login?error=true") 
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/")          
                .and().logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout=true").permitAll()
                .and().rememberMe().key("uniqueAndSecret"); 
    }
}
```

[image: Detalle deprecación]

Answer (score 0):

No se si has conseguido solución, pero básicamente han habido una actualización Spring Security, y básicamente hay que utilizar lambdas, aquí te dejo el código:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfiguration {

@Autowired
private UserDetailsService serviceUsuario;

String[] resources = new String[] { "/include/**", "/js/**", "/css/**"}; 

@Bean
BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}

protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(serviceUsuario).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder()) ;
}

@Bean
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth.requestMatchers(resources)
            .permitAll()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated());
    
    http.formLogin(fl -> fl.failureUrl("/login?error=true").defaultSuccessUrl("/")
    );

    http.logout(lo -> lo.logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout=true").permitAll());

    http.rememberMe(rm -> rm.key("uniqueAndSecret"));

}
}
```

Espero que eso te ayude, te adjunto también un conjunto de tutoriales donde actualiza esto, mira el video 33 y 36 y estate atento a las actualizaciones que por lo visto suele haber periodicamente:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qAyzpljhyIs&list=PL4bT56Uw3S4z9rtwwGvuk1Mjhu5sdLSwX&index=36